# How to find exact place for given value in python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have one dictionary with key and value. Key is row name and values is the last seat number. I would like to find the row number based on the input value.

```
seats_dict={'A':10,'B':'20':'C':30}
```

**Input:**

seat_num =16

**Output:**
Should be **'B'**

Is there any function to identity this in python?

Comment: What are the boundaries like - What would Seat 31 or 41 as input give you? Does every seat row always have 10 seats?

Comment: boundary values is from 1 to 30. row always 10 seats

Comment: Is there a reason you need to have this in a dictionary? It doesn't seem like the right structure if this is all you need it for.

Comment: I needed row and seat relation, so that's why I chose dictionary.

Comment: Are the row names alphabetically sequential (A, B, C, D...)? What is the last row number?

Comment: yes it alphabetical sequential. last row number is 'G'.

Comment: In that case the simple function I posted will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the *boundary values is from 1 to 30. row always 10 seats*... you're better of building a list of the values, then indexing, eg:

```
seats = ''.join(row * 10 for row in 'ABC') # add DEFG etc.. for additional rows
try:
    print seats[15] # note Python indices are 0 based
except IndexError:
    pass # no row found - do something
```

That way you can also naturally check the boundaries / add more rows - change seat sizes for each row...

You can include the rows by using a nested list-comp, eg:

```
seats = ['{}{}'.format(r, n) for r in 'ABC' for n in range(1, 11)]
#['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'A9', 'A10', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B9', 'B10', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'C10']
```

then index the same as above - eg: `seats[15]` gives `'B6'`

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your dictionary would be more useful inverted in terms of keys and values.

i.e seats_dict={10: 'A', 20: 'B', 30: 'C'}

You then just need to find the lowest key such that last_key < n is <= key. You could do that with a binary search potentially.

As @Jon alludes to, things would be even easier if there are always 10 seats to a row (you might not need a dictionary at all).

Comment: This answer would be useful for uneven length rows. See my other answer for the simple fixed row length case.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the `seats_dict` does not hold a full map for seats and sections, but only the end number of each section.

> `seats_dict={'A':10,'B':'20':'C':30}`
>
> Input:
>
> seat_num =16 ## Note: I don't see 16 in the dict
>
> Output: Should be 'B'

How about this lookup function:

```
def get_row(seat_num):
    seat_ranges = {10: "A", 20: "B", 30: "C"} # inverted dict
    matching_ranges = [k for k in seat_ranges if k >= seat_num]
    if not matching_ranges:
        raise ValueError("No row found for seat number %d" % seat_num)
    return seat_ranges.get(min(matching_ranges))
```

Sample output:

```
>>> get_row(16)
'B'
>>> get_row(17)
'B'
>>> get_row(31)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in get_row
ValueError: No row found for seat number 31

row_name = {k:seat_ranges[k] for k in d if k>1}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any built-in python function to do this, but you'd do well to use a quick list comprehension that filters your dictionary and returns the first value.

Note that the sorting makes it work regardless of dictionary order:

```
seats_dict={'A':10,'C': 30, 'B':20}

seats_num = 16

print sorted([row for row in seats_dict if seats_dict[row] >= seats_num])[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
def seat(n):
    if n > 260 or n < 1:
      raise ValueError("Seat number must be between 1 and 260 (inclusive)")
    return chr(ord('A') + ((n - 1) // 10))
```

Comment: seat(1) = A, seat(2) = A, seat(10) = A, seat(11) = B, seat(21) = C